# Why does only two of my divs go inline and the third ends up underneath?

Tags: html, css

I am making something where i need a 3x3 square with divs. I first made three columns, and thought that i could make three squares in each column. But the three divs within the columns dont go inline.

```css
#one {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 30vh;
}

#two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.333%;
}

#three {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.333%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried searching for other results on the internet, but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique. Try classes instead

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of issues.  The first being that id's need to be unique.  With what you are doing you want to use class.  I added borders on the divs so you can see what's going on.  You need to take those borders into account when figuring out the width.  Lastly, outside the #one the rest of the div's should be inline-block.

A better way to do stuff like this is to use flexbox.

```css
#one {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 30vw ;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.two {
    height:100%;
    width:calc(33.333% - 6px);
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.three {
   height:100%; 
    width: calc(33.333% - 6px);
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

div{
  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="one">
        <div class="two">
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```